# Alternative for having LUIS Intent

Tags: asp.net-web-api, botframework, azure-language-understanding, stop-words

The requirement is to capture the keywords from the user input given in chat window and make a web api call to get a file link.

I have four different categories into which the user input query can be classified:

--Operating Group
--Technology
--Geography
--Themes

I have configured a LUIS intent and listed these four categories as entitites. However, the issue now is that the entity list cannot be predefined since there can be any number 
of search keywords which can be passed to web api. I am now confused if there is any other way round for this requirement such as removing the stop words and passing the list of keywords 
Web API.

Code :

```
           [LuisIntent("Credentials")]
    public async Task Credentials(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        try
        {                
            if (result.Entities.Count() == 0)
            {
                if ((result.Query.ToString().ToLower() == "geo" || result.Query.ToString().ToLower() == "operating group" || result.Query.ToString().ToLower() == "technology" || result.Query.ToString().ToLower() == "Themes"))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    await context.Forward(new QnABotFeedbackDialog(updateQna, result.Query, rotationTemStorage, qnaInvalidMessageCount), AfterCredentialDialog, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
            else if (result.Entities.Count() > 0)
            {                    
                string efilterType = string.Empty;
                if (result.Entities.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var i in result.Entities)
                    {
                        if (efilterType == string.Empty)
                        {
                            efilterType = i.Entity;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            efilterType = efilterType + "," + i.Entity;
                        }
                    }
                }
                await CredentialsPersonalisation(context, efilterType);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's hard to give a reply here without knowing more details about your context: what would be the user input (please give some samples, for each categories), how would you call your API after the detection (several APIs ? Only one with parameters for each category?)

Comment: CATEGORIES:
Geography - { "AAPAC", "North America",.}
Operating Group - { "FS", "PRD",.}
Technology -{ "Blue Prism", "Pega".}
Agile - { "CoE", "Run Support". })
We have a single API which would take search keyword and give the corresponding file link.
There is no limit on the search keyword count, the API accepts any number of search keywords
The requirement now is to take the search keywords directly from user input text and send it to web API.
Ex: give me the file for fs in north america region on RPA =>send FS,North America,RPA to Web API

Comment: So you should create 3 entities (not closed lists), add several utterances with variations of these entities values then train your model

Comment: yes, that was the idea. However, we do not have a fixed set of keywords which we could pre-configure in Entity lists. For example, user could even ask for a Geography value(Say Europe) not defined in Entity List - Even in such case we should capture the keyword and send to web API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, we do not have a fixed set of keywords which we could
>   pre-configure in Entity lists.

I think you misunderstood what an entity is.
`Simple` entities are not pre-configured lists, it learns from your utterances and for the calls after. So it's basically what you want. So you have to create your three entities as simple, then add utterances and tag the entities in those utterances. Do not use always the same value for an entity.

For example, add the following utterances:

```
give me the file for fs in North America region on RPA
```

And tag `fs` as `OperationGroup` entity, `North America` as `Geography` entity, and `RPA` as `Technology` entity

```
Can I have the file for PRD in Europe about LUIS?
```

And tag `PRD` as `OperationGroup` entity, `Europe` as `Geography` entity, and `LUIS` as `Technology` entity

Sidenote: if you have fixed lists, which is not the case here, you must create an entity of type `List`:
[image]

Comment: 1)I actually have configured the entities(4 different) under Entity Type LIST, so I should be changing it to simple Entity?         2)When there is a new query for EMEA region and if it has not been added in Entity, will it even be picked as the keyword for Web API call?

Comment: 1) Yes, remove the existing Entity List. 2) Yes, that's the purpose of entities: the aim is not to code a Regexp ;-)