# luis patterns does not identify all entity utterances

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

We have a bot designed in C# SDK V3. 
The functionality is such that upon user input, the query is passed to qnamaker and the answers are given to the user. If there is no answer found in the qnamaker, the search is 
directed to sharepoint.

There was a new requirement wherein upon asking for any search keyword, the bot has to give the user a processed file - a web api was implemented for this purpose. The issue started while trying to integrate this web api in the bot.

A new intent was added to invoke this web api. However, adding this intent has disturbed the existing functionality. Hence, I have decided to proceed with the patterns- add simple entity and have a patterns.

I am not sure if adding patterns is the correct solution for this issue. The problem I face now is when I test within the qnamaker after adding all the entity utterances, the pattern based input does not show the entity or pattern prediction for some of the utterances even after training it several times.

Comment: Do you think you could add any examples?

Comment: I have added the pattern 'I want to get the file for {Entity}'. However, when I test in Luis portal, not all entity utterances show the matching pattern.

Comment: Do you use List or other type of entity?

Comment: I was initially using list type entity but I have now changed it to simple type since we do not have a fixed number of search keywords - please refer [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54918690/alternative-for-having-luis-intent)

Comment: The issue doesn't necessarily seem to be the pattern feature of LUIS, perhaps, but instead there's an issue with entity detection--the LUIS model needs to be built out more with more training data on when/where the simple entity may occur. -- also good switch from list entity to simple entity, since with list you can only detect the entities you specify (no machine learning, only exact text match). So I would 1. try improving entity detection first by building the model more 2. verify if the pattern is detecting the pattern properly, BUT there aren't entities being detected (potential bug)

Comment: I'll post links to the SO posts describing how to build out the model to improve entity detection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752218/luis-list-entity/52769408#52769408

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930061/dispatch-cli-not-passing-entities-from-luis-app/55012604#55012604

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650025/luis-intent-not-returning-the-entire-value-of-the-entity-with-space/52656368#52656368

Comment: Thanks @Zeryth, your suggestion of training the model more and more helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by following Zeryth's suggestion of training the model and publishing the Luis model again.