# integrate web api in bot framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, botframework, azure-language-understanding

We have a bot designed in C# SDK V3. The functionality is such that upon user input, the query is passed to qnamaker and the answers are given to the user. If there is no answer found in the qnamaker, the search is directed to sharepoint.

There was a new requirement wherein upon asking for any search keyword, the bot has to give the user a processed file - a web api was implemented for this purpose. The issue started while trying to integrate this web api in the bot.

The web api searches the user input search keywords through an excel spreadsheet and then deletes the unwanted slides in pptx file based on IDs found in excel.

1. to add a new intent for a web api call is proving to be difficult since many keywords have been added in other intents and it breaks the conversation flow in bot.
2. adding patterns has not helped since many entities are not being recognized.

What's tbe best approach for this requirement?

Comment: I'm sorry but points 1) and 2) are not clear to me and for more they might deserve separate question. Do you think you could split your question into "Bot and WebApi" and "Webapi for static file modification"?

Comment: I have added those points as these two are the approaches I have tried implementing - adding another intent and adding patterns. I want to know if there is any other way to implement the web api call without disturbing the existing flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [luis patterns does not identify all entity utterances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215111/luis-patterns-does-not-identify-all-entity-utterances)